# Re-write a GLM function using mathematical notation

Tags: r, glm

I am using the following glm function in R:

glm(Delta ~ factor * proportion + N * proportion + N * factor, family = "gaussian", data = df)

where Delta and proportion are continuous variables from -1 to 1
and factor is a categorical with 5 levels and N is a categorical with 2 levels

How would I re-write this function in equation format using mathematical notation

Comment: You can't.  The `glm()` function does a lot more than evaluate mathematical expressions.

Comment: @user2554330 is right.  Alternatively, are you wondering how you _would_ write the function in mathematical notation - not to hand to R, but to describe the model in mathematical notation?  If so, it's a question better suited to [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally I would say this is a math/stats question, not a programming question, but R does actually know how to answer this question (code below)

[image: equation outcome]

Although this is mathematically correct, it is a slightly clunky way to define things — `f2`, `f3`, `f4`, `f5` are *dummy variables* (i.e. `f2=1` if a particular observation has `f` == level 2); others might write the first few terms out as `alpha + gamma[f[i]]`

Note I have done this with `lm()`, which is equivalent to `glm` with `family=gaussian`

---

```r
library(equatiomatic)
library(tinytex)

dd <- data.frame(Delta = rnorm(100), prop = runif(100), N = factor(1:2), f = factor(1:5))
m1 <- lm(Delta ~ f*prop + N*prop + N*f, dd)

eq <- extract_eq(m1, wrap = TRUE)
writeLines(con = "SO71692903.tex",
           text = c("\\documentclass{article}",
                    "\\usepackage{amsmath}",
                    "\\begin{document}",
                    "$$",
                    eq,
                    "$$",
                    "\\end{document}"))
latexmk("SO71692903.tex")
browseURL("SO71692903.pdf")
```